# How can I show/hide HTML elements if the page is_front_page

Tags: homepage

For example if its `'is_front_page'` I want to hide a div. If its not the `'is_front_page'` i want to show the div. How can i achieve this?

I am not sure on how I can achieve this. Any assistance would be great. Thanks

Comment: I am struggling to figure out what part it is that you need help with. You found the conditional tag you want to use - where exactly is the problem now?

Comment: I am not sure on how to hide and show the elements. Meaning I am not sure on what the proper way of writing it is.

Comment: The "conditional tag" `is_front_page` is a PHP (server-side) function that returns a boolean value. Hence you can use it inside a PHP conditional to wrap the HTML output in. "Showing/Hiding" sort of implies client-side action. What do you want/need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really not enough information, so I have to guess.

#### A) The *div* is part of the content

Use PHP, check for front-page, and if not, handle the div:

```
<?php if (! is_front_page()) : ?>
    <div />
<?php endif; ?>
```

#### B) The *div* is located somewhere else on the page

Give the div an ID and use jQuery:

```
<?php if (! is_front_page()) : ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('#DIV-ID-HERE').remove();
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**// EDIT**
Of course, method A should be preferred! I'd suggest to include the above code where the div is generated.

Comment: Method A worked for my project. Thanks for your time and assistance.